# AWS Connection for RDS mysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and I am not able to connect to Amazon RDS through eclipse.

I get the exception :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.rds.ImportWizard.performFinish(ImportWizard.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.explorer.rds.RDSExplorerActionProvider$ConfigureConnectionProfileAction.run(RDSExplorerActionProvider.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
**Caused by: AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonRDS, AWS Request ID: ***************, AWS Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination, AWS Error Message: Cannot apply DB Security Group membership to DB Instance in VPC.Please use VPC Security Groups instead.**
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:659)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:347)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:2423)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.modifyDBInstance(AmazonRDSClient.java:1757)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.rds.ConfigureRDSDBConnectionRunnable.openSecurityGroupIngress(ConfigureRDSDBConnectionRunnable.java:126)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.rds.ConfigureRDSDBConnectionRunnable.run(ConfigureRDSDBConnectionRunnable.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

I have gone through all the documents but some how i am not able to do it.
    Through Cli its working i can reach:

```
mytestrds.**********.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

This Gives me the response back but when i connect it through eclipse it doesnt work and throws the exception.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you trying to connect to RDS through your eclipse.

Comment: Either the security groups in AWS isn't right or Eclipse doesn't use it properly.

Comment: Hi Chen, Jeevan, I Have deployed a sample project through eclipse,I have Database instance created with security group it also has VPC Id. I Also tried to create new VPC and created new Security group but for some reason that security group will not be available in DB instance dropdown of security group. From eclipse under AWS explorer i have DB instance and doule click and provide the user name and it throws the exception. I tried  mysql -h myinstance.mydnsnameexample.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p. same issue as https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=477988#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993956/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-through-eclipse/24994339?noredirect=1#comment38923963_24994339

I had similar problems.. hope this helps